# How to get mysql server info using command line?

Tags: mysql

Is there a direct command line command that provides all mysql server information like below...This is provided using Mysql GUI administrator. Do we have some direct command to get this info  ussing command line ?

Username:
Hostname:
Port:
**Server Information**
MySQL Version:
Network Name:
IP:
**Client Information**
Version:
Network name:
IP:
Operating System:
Hardware:

Answer (score 33):

Look at following MySQL documentation:

[SHOW VARIABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-variables.html)

**Following command will show you most of your desired information:**

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
```

**Only version:**

```
select version();
```

---

**EDIT:**

*What is the difference between show variables and show status?*

**SHOW STATUS**  provides server status information like `Connections`, `Opened_tables`, `Bytes_received`, `Bytes_sent`, etc.

[More Info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html)

**SHOW VARIABLES** shows the values of MySQL system variables like `time_zone`, `version`, `max_connections`, etc.

[More Info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-variables.html)

Answer (score 31):

Try just `status`:

```
mysql> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.33, for osx10.7 (i386) using readline 5.1

Connection id:      3
Current database:   somedb
Current user:       someuser@localhost
SSL:            Not in use
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server version:     5.5.33 Source distribution
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
TCP port:       3306
Uptime:         38 min 53 sec

Threads: 2  Questions: 196  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 87  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 80  Queries per second avg: 0.084
--------------
```